# add a borders to all cells of excel even the empty one using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I add a border to cells i used in the excel, but i need to put borders to all cells on the excel even the empty one

[image]

Comment: Have you ever considered using Jxls ? it is very easy to set the cell boarder like you do in the excel file. you problem I guess is that you didn't have real cell objects generated in the program for those so called "empty cells" so the boarders are not applied to those empty ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind the JXLS is that you Pre-set all kind of time consuming parts(styling, layout...) into a template and your main job is is to establish the back-end beans and fill up this template with those beans.

This is very a very neat tool which makes you focus more on business logic instead of programming for those styling stuff  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a white character (e.g. "space") into empty cells.